# Reinstalling .NET Framework 1.0

Tags: .net

I am having to reinstall .NET Framework from 1.0 and up, however, during the install of 1.0 I am asked where do I want to put the files.  I am not sure, but in my researching, would I be correct to put them here:**C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v1.0.3705**

I can't get this computer online because the system owner deleted some files and now the drive won't read any setup files, so I'm really stuck here.

These are the messages received when attempting to install.
.NET Framework 1.0 Service Pack 3 – Message box – NET Framework 1.0 SP 3 – The upgrade Patch cannot be installed by Windows installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing or the upgrade may update a different version of the program.

.NET Framework 1.1 – Setup complete.

.NET Framework l.l Service Pack 1 – Successfully installed on Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1.  Must restart computer..Click yes.  However, when restarted computer got message box - hpqimzone.exe – Common Language Runtime Debugging Services - Heading

.NET Framework 2.0 – Successfully Installed.

.NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 1 – Message box - Setup has detected that this computer does not meet the requirement to install this software.  These requirements must be met before you can install Microsoft NET Framework 2.0 SP1.

.NET Framework 3.0 – Message box – You must install this service pack to complete installation.  Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 requires that this service pack be installed prior to installation.  Service Pack 2

Comment: You really need to mention what OS it is.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to be much better off and have a much simpler time if you reinstall the OS.

Comment: Should I then do a clean reinstall?

Comment: @RoberLumpkin: yes, after backing up all important data.

Comment: Ok, I'll attempt another OS install.  Should I do a repartition as well?

Comment: I think the partitioning question should direct to Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 3.5 SP1 will install the most recent versions of previous major releases; it looks like it includes:

- v1.0.3705
- v1.1.4322
- v2.0.50727
- v3.0
- v3.5

Try installing the most recent version and see what happens, but you probably are better off backing up user data and reloading.

Comment: And here is the link to .NET 3.5 SP1 Redistributable, so you can install it without the need for an internet connection: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe

Comment: Here are the messages I got when trying to install vers.3.5 SP! 



You must install this service pack to complete installation.  Microsoft NET Framework 3.5 requires that this service pack be installed prior to the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Aaron's](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/04/08/406671.aspx) blog post which helped me some while ago about .net installation failures that i had.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out, though I did find some of his post when researching.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do it that way.  All you need are these:

- [Windows Installer 3.1 v2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893803)
- [.NET 3.5 SP1 (Full Install)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe)
- [.NET 3.5 SP1 Compatibility Hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959209)

Comment: Won't I need to uninstall all vers of .NET and then install just these two?